# MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE Not Work In Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview, crop

In my android app, I have a crop image. So, I programming a `CropBox` that extends `ImageView`. I want to move and resize the crop box. I use `OnTouchListener`, But MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE not work. I google it but I don't catch anything.

Attr Class:

```
public class Attr {

    public static final float CROP_BOX_START_X = 5;
    public static final float CROP_BOX_START_Y = 5;
    public static final float CROP_BOX_END_X = 305;
    public static final float CROP_BOX_END_Y = 105;

}
```

CropBox Class:

```
public class CropBox extends ImageView {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();


    public CropBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CropBox(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float[][] circleXY = {
            {Attr.CROP_BOX_START_X, Attr.CROP_BOX_START_Y},
            {(Attr.CROP_BOX_START_X + Attr.CROP_BOX_END_X) / 2, Attr.CROP_BOX_START_Y},
            {Attr.CROP_BOX_END_X, Attr.CROP_BOX_START_Y},
            {Attr.CROP_BOX_START_X, Attr.CROP_BOX_END_Y},
            {(Attr.CROP_BOX_START_X + Attr.CROP_BOX_END_X) / 2, Attr.CROP_BOX_END_Y},
            {Attr.CROP_BOX_END_X, Attr.CROP_BOX_END_Y},
            {Attr.CROP_BOX_START_X, (Attr.CROP_BOX_START_Y + Attr.CROP_BOX_END_Y) / 2},
            {Attr.CROP_BOX_END_X, (Attr.CROP_BOX_START_Y + Attr.CROP_BOX_END_Y) / 2}
        };
        float[][] lineXY = {
            {Attr.CROP_BOX_START_X, Attr.CROP_BOX_START_Y, Attr.CROP_BOX_END_X, Attr.CROP_BOX_START_Y},
            {Attr.CROP_BOX_START_X, Attr.CROP_BOX_END_Y, Attr.CROP_BOX_END_X, Attr.CROP_BOX_END_Y},
            {Attr.CROP_BOX_START_X, Attr.CROP_BOX_START_Y, Attr.CROP_BOX_START_X, Attr.CROP_BOX_END_Y},
            {Attr.CROP_BOX_END_X, Attr.CROP_BOX_START_Y, Attr.CROP_BOX_END_X, Attr.CROP_BOX_END_Y}
        };

        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < circleXY.length ; i++)
            canvas.drawCircle(circleXY[i][0], circleXY[i][1], 5, paint);

        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < lineXY.length ; i++)
            canvas.drawLine(lineXY[i][0], lineXY[i][1], lineXY[i][2], lineXY[i][3], paint);
    }

}
```

CropTestActivity Class:

```
public class CropTestActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private CropBox cropBorder;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.crop_test_layout);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.android_image);
        cropBorder = new CropBox(this);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.crop_test_layout);
        layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = imageView.getViewTreeObserver();
        if(viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
            viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = imageView.getWidth() / 2 - (int)((Attr.CROP_BOX_START_X + Attr.CROP_BOX_END_X) / 2) + imageView.getLeft();
                    layoutParams.topMargin = imageView.getHeight() / 2 - (int)((Attr.CROP_BOX_START_Y + Attr.CROP_BOX_END_Y) / 2) + imageView.getTop();
                }
            });
        }
        relativeLayout.addView(cropBorder, layoutParams);
        cropBorder.setOnTouchListener(new Crop());
    }

}
```

Crop Class:

```
public class Crop implements OnTouchListener {

    private static final int NONE = 0;
    private static final int BOX_DRAG = 1;
    private static final int BORDER_DRAG = 2;

    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    private PointF start = new PointF();

    private int mode = NONE;

    private float cropBoxStartX = Attr.CROP_BOX_START_X;
    private float cropBoxStartY = Attr.CROP_BOX_START_Y;
    private float cropBoxEndX = Attr.CROP_BOX_END_X;
    private float cropBoxEndY = Attr.CROP_BOX_END_Y;

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        CropBox cropBox = (CropBox)view;

        switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                if(event.getX() > cropBoxStartX && event.getX() < cropBoxEndX && event.getY() > cropBoxStartY && event.getY() < cropBoxEndY)
                    mode = BOX_DRAG;
                else if(event.getX() == cropBoxStartX || event.getX() == cropBoxEndX || event.getY() == cropBoxStartY || event.getY() == cropBoxEndY)
                    mode = BORDER_DRAG;
                else
                    mode = NONE;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(mode == BOX_DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
                }
                else if(mode == BORDER_DRAG) {  
                }
                break;
        }
        cropBox.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/crop_test_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/android_image"
        android:src="@drawable/android"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="@string/android_image_description" >
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your implementation is right, the only thing that I didn't see is you setting the scale type of your CropBox to MATRIX to be able to use setImageMatrix.

Comment: Actually I forget to set scale type to matrix. But It's not working yet.